# How to spawn new processes in latest iOS SDK?

Tags: ios

As Apple allowed IDE-like application in AppStore, there are some apps like [Continuous](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/continuous-net-c-and-f-ide/id1095213378?mt=8), [CppCode](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cppcode-offline-c-c-ide-compiler/id936694712?mt=8), [Pythonista](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pythonista-3/id1085978097?mt=8), even Apple's official [Swift Playgrounds](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/swift-playgrounds/id908519492?mt=8), letting users typing in source code, compiling and running them locally. I did a few tries but it seems `system()` call is still forbidden in the latest iOS SDK (version 11.2), and `NSTask` is also not available. So how does the above IDEs run the compiler and the compiled executable? And quick examples?

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say they wrote their own compilers or ported/compiled them for iOS. How are you trying to compile something with `system()` or `NSTask`?

Comment: CppCode claims that it used the embedded libc.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Yes they did ported the compiler to iOS. Despite that, I guess they still need to call the compile anyway, like ‘system(“gcc main.c”)’ and system(“a.out”).

Comment: @LingfengXiong not really. If you bundle the library with your app, or if you create a compiler within your app, you can call it like you would any other C function, no need to run another executable.